# QuickOSM plugin not working

Tags: qgis, quickosm

Since today, I cannot open the QuickOSM plugin in QGIS 3.4.

I tried to delete and reinstall - to no avail.

The XYZ OSM tile is still working as usual.

When I click on the magnifier -QuickOSM button, it starts to load but never finishes.....

Any ideas?

Comment: The latest version was uploaded only a few days ago (11/11/2019). Were you using this version when it stopped working? Could you try the [previous version](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/version/1.13.1/) and see if this one works?

Comment: Which version of QuickOSM are you using? Indeed, there was an update last monday, version 1.14.0. Can you open your QGIS Logs, the small bubble right bottom corner, and check if there something interesting.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the feedback. I downloaded the version 1.14.0. But it is working again... I do not get an error again.

Comment: By the way, many thanks for this useful plugin. It is very helpful..